# Get calendar event ID after adding it by user

Tags: java, android

I have a question: how to get properly calendar event ID? I have this code to add event:

```
Intent addMeetingEvent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, appBeginTimeDate.getMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, appEndTimeDate.getMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "title")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "desc")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
        startActivity(addMeetingEvent);


//in here the eventID is null, cause it has not been confirmed and saved by the user
//long eventID = Long.parseLong(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.getLastPathSegment());
```

So first I create the intent and put extras than the Android callendar lauches and shows the event. Then user needs to cofirm it (or cancel). My question is - how and when do I get eventID?
I need to store it, so it the event can be deleted (if user clicks so).

**EDIT:**
After Jon Skeet adviced me I used startActivityForResult. My callback is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == 0){//EXCEPTION LINE BELOW
            Uri dataUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("TEST", dataUri.toString());
        }

    }

And I have an exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {xxx.BookAppointmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3219)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at xxx.BookAppointmentActivity.onActivityResult(BookAppointmentActivity.java:202)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3219)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: thank you, this looks okay. But have another problem. This - CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.getLastPathSegment() - return only String "events" instead of eventId. Do you know the solution? This example is exactly from Android Developers website, I thought it should work nice.

Comment: Well why are you calling `getLastPathSegment()`? And why are you trying to use `CONTENT_URI`, which is a *constant* value?

Comment: Now I know it's wrong. But there is no example how to get ID when using intent to add event. There is an example using ContentValues, but no with intents. When using intent http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-edit the id is set eventId=208 :/ but how to get it they do not mention. Is this possible to get the ID when using intents to add event?

Comment: Well have you looked at the data you get back from `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Based on example found I tried to do: Uri dataUri = data.getData(); but I get NullPointerException. Could you look at my edited question?

Comment: I suggest you examine this in a debugger. It's nothing I've ever done before - I'm not an Android developer - I'm just suggesting things based on the documentation. (We don't know which line is 202 for example...)

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i am having the same q: how to get the event id after adding an event using an intent. thanks!